# How to SetTransObject to Sybase DataWindow in Visual Studio .NET WPF C# Application

Tags: c#, wpf, powerbuilder.net

I have a WPF C# Application. I'm using a `Sybase.PowerBuilder.WPF.Controls.DataWindow`, but I don't know how to use `SetTransObject`.

This is some of my code:

```
using Sybase.PowerBuilder.WPF.Controls;
partial class xxx
{ 
   public xxx()
   {
      Sybase.PowerBuilder.WPF.Controls.DataWindow DW_1 =
         new Sybase.PowerBuilder.WPF.Controls.DataWindow();
      DW_1.DataObject = "eee";
      DW_1.SetTransObject();
   }
}
```

Comment: Can You add some piece of code presenting Your problem? Also You could add some details to the question.

Comment: Ok i will add some piece of code

Answer (score 0):

That control really isn't intended to be used outside of the PowerBuilder.Net environment.  I can imagine that you'd run into a number of issues trying to use it directly from VS.Net.  In this particular instance, SetTransObject takes a PowerBuilder.Net database connection object.  You might be best service by creating a visual user object in PowerBuilder.Net and then using that from VS.Net.